# How to convert hg19.bit file to hg19.fa file using twobitreader?

Tags: python

I have tried this code in pyhthon shell prompt using windows. but I am getting the error as follows

```
>>> python -m twobitreader hg19.2bit < example.bed
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried with the code you have sent

```
import twobitreader
     with open("fas.fa", "w") as output, open('example.bed') as bedfile:
     twobit = twobitreader.TwoBitFile('hg19.2bit')
     twobitreader.twobit_reader(twobit, input_stream=bedfile, write=output)
```

When I try to execute the above code I am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/genome/sample6.py", line 3, in <module>
with open("fas.fa", "w") as output, open('example.bed') as bedfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example.bed'`Filed:
```

I unable to trace the error exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a *shell command* in the Python interpreter. The interpreter is **not** a shell.

Inside the shell you can still execute the same code the command line code would. Both a `2bit` file *and* the input stream is be required for `twobit_reader()` to do anything. The [first line of the function](http://pythonhosted.org//twobitreader/_modules/twobitreader.html#twobit_reader) reads:

```
if input_stream is None: return
```

The library takes the `hg19.2bit` file as a `TwoBitFile` object; the *`input_stream`* argument must be a file or other iterable in using the *BED format*, according to the documentation string for the command line tool:

> Regions should be given in BED format on stdin
>
> ```
> chrom    start(0-based)    end(0-based, not included)
> ```
>
> To use a BED file of regions, do
>
> ```
> python -m twobitreader example.2bit < example.bed
> ```

From a Python script, the `example.bed` input should be an open file passed in as `input_stream`:

```
import twobitreader

with open("fas.fa", "w") as output, open('example.bed') as bedfile:
    twobit = twobitreader.TwoBitFile('hg19.2bit')
    twobitreader.twobit_reader(twobit, input_stream=bedfile, write=output)
```

The project documentation provides a link for the BED format: http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat#format1

Comment: For python I am using windows platform.  I think the command           "python -m twobitreader example.2bit < example.bed"  will work in Linux. But in windows platform how to create bed file for hg19.2bit file using python. If I use the above command in DOS prompt/python shell it shows error msg as invalid syntax. Then what will be the code to create bed file in python.

Comment: `python -m twobitreader example.2bit < example.bed` can be translated to the code in my answer; replace `some_bed_file` with `example.bed`.

Comment: However, I am fairly certain Windows supports input redirection the same way Linux does.

Comment: i have made changes in the code as above but still i unable to generate bed file.

Comment: @CHITRA: you mean *generate a FASTA file*? Because the code doesn't generate a BED file, it takes such a file as *input*.

Comment: @CHITRA: other than that I have no such files so I cannot test the execution. All I can do at this point is look at the module and explain how it is supposed to work. My answer replicates what the command-line options do.

Comment: @CHITRA: you tried to execute the command line *in the python interpreter*. Open `CMD.exe` and run the command *there*, with `python.exe`. The command line example is **not** Python code itself, it just instructs the computer to run the Python executable with the script.

Comment: Yes i need to generate fasta file. As per your suggestion I tried to run the code "python -m twobitreader hg19.2bit < example.bed" in cmd.exe. But I am getting the error as File "<stdin>",line 1                                                     python -m twobitreader hg19.2bit < ex.bed : Syntax error:invalid syntax

Comment: @CHITRA: no, that error indicates you tried to run it inside Python instead.